# Alexa ranked dropped by a million since last week

Tags: alexa

I have a website on that ranks pretty good on Alexa, but last week it dropped by 1 millon in rank!

*Questions:*

- Why the sudden drop?
- How do I improve my Alexa rank?

Comment: The reason is your site is not getting enough traffic. Alexa depends on traffic.

Comment: See also: [Why do Alexa rankings for a site fluctuate by millions day to day?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58602/why-do-alexa-rankings-for-a-site-fluctuate-by-millions-day-to-day)

Comment: For the "How do I improve my Alexa rank?" question, see: [How to improve the Alexa rank of my website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67717/how-to-improve-the-alexa-rank-of-my-website)

Answer (score 4):

Alexa ranking is pretty meaningless, *especially* for sites outside the top 1000. It's measured from people who have the Alexa toolbar installed - if none of your visitors have it installed, then you will not even register on Alexa's radar.

You also have to ask yourself why you care about the ranking. What does the information give you? You should already have some real visitor tracking (e.g. Google Analytics) and know exactly how many people are actually visiting. So knowing Alexa's guess of the number of visitors to your site doesn't really give you any more information.

Comment: Are you sure about having to have the bar installed? I'm just wondering because I can't really imagine anybody having that installed in their computer, besides of course people that don't even realize it.

Comment: yes, @DisgruntledGoat is right. Alexa gets it's data from people who have installed their toolbar. Whenever I am working on a website, people notice a spike in their alexa rank because I have got the toolbar installed.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question was re-opened, I will post my comment as an answer:

I'm not sure of what has happened of lately, but one of my websites fell down 8,036,040 from previous months on alexa's rank.

It could be that they have adjusted their systems for more (or less) precise measurements, but I haven't noticed any drops in traffic from google analytics for example.

Everything else seems normal and the number of daily visitors appears to be the same as well. I wouldn't worry too much about it, unless you notice a sudden drop in other measuring tools / visitors as well.

Comment: Since it is Alexa I wouldn't worry about it at all

Answer (score 0):

Alexa ranking should be used as an orientative value, but not much than that. If you have your own visitors tracking system, then there is where your concerns should be, as well as checking if your traffic is converting adequately.