# Why do Alexa rankings for a site fluctuate by millions day to day?

Tags: alexa

Yesterday before I went to  bed, I checked the Alexa ranking for my website and it was somewhere in the ~4 million but today when I woke up, it was back at what it used to be months ago which was 18 million. What happened?

So when I first created the website, my Alexa ranking was 18 million then it dropped to 12 million then 7 million and yesterday it dropped to 4 million and today in the morning was back to 18 million. I mean nothing has changed from yesterday, everything is the same. I checked my Google Webmaster Tools and Google Analytics and there's nothing wrong.

Comment: As covered by many other questions here, Alexa is useless and relies on users using their toolbar. You shouldn't pay attention to their data, it's irrelevant. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=alexa+rank

Comment: for my webpage, alexa in free version has nearly similiar numbers like google analytics has for my page

Comment: That is a very rare case.

Comment: I is a strange case it don't happens generally, may be you are loosing your backlinks this may cause this problem.

Comment: See also: [Alexa ranked dropped by a million since last week](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53001/alexa-traffic-dropping-in-rank)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simple answer. Alexa is junk. Do not even look at it. Only for the most active sites will the Alexa number mean anything. Otherwise, it will be a misleading metric that should not be paid attention to.

The reason is that Alexa has to extrapolate their results based upon a self-selective group. Alexa says that it's toolbar users are diverse, however, clearly it is a self-selected group regardless - meaning that the data sample is provided by only those who would install the Alexa toolbar. In the statistics game, that is a disaster. Only random samples work. Even then, the larger the sample size the better. Think about it. Who installs the Alexa toolbar anymore? Especially when they get a new computer? The Alexa audience is becoming narrower as fewer people install the toolbar and those who do fit within a smaller group of those who would. It was a flawed system right from the start. At least from a statistics analysis point of view.

To that end, sites with less traffic have less sample data to make any clear indication. This is why Alexa varies so widely and hence why you should not pay attention to the metric at all.

[Update]

I had taken the time to definitively prove why Alexa metrics are junk on my own website found here http://www.closetnoc.org/?i=definitive-proof-that-alexa-sucks (I hesitate to link to my own site, but this is well worth a read for a complete understanding). Here are just some of the takeaways that I can add here without long explanation:

- The Alexa Toolbar is only compatible with 2/3rds of the popular web
  browsers.
- The Alexa Toolbar is largely incompatible with mobile search which is
  at least 1/3rd of search.
- Alexa cannot know about the statistical population of users who use
  browsers that are not supported by Alexa, mobile users, developing
  countries, non-Alexa users, and so on.
- In statistical analysis, it is impossible to correct for biases using
  a population you do not know.
- The Alexa Toolbar users are self-selective toward blog users, Twitter
  users, Facebook users, and other social media.
- The Alexa Toolbar users are self-selective toward content and sites
  that are trend based and not research based.
- The Alexa Toolbar users are self-selective away from research sites
  and search engine usage.
- The Alexa Toolbar users trend toward popular topics/sites and those
  who concern themselves toward popular topics- this means a younger
  demographic and a demographic that does not include older or senior
  users.
- The Alexa Toolbar not being mobile compatible, has lost many millions
  of young users in the past two years and growing- trending toward a
  smaller audience that is becoming more middle aged.
- The Alexa Toolbar is losing popularity and new computer users, who
  once used the Alexa Toolbar, are opting not to re-install the toolbar
  on a new computers.
- The Alexa bug is not 100% accurate with complaints on it's
  effectiveness to capture accurate usage.
- The Alexa bug cannot compensate for a population that is not known.
- Alexa favors Alexa ratings and reviews with bias.
- Alexa favors trend sites with bias.
- Alexa favors social media usage with bias.

Comment: The reason why Alexa ranking is important to me is because people who want to do business with me, they look me up on Alexa ranking and see if my business is worth it. This is why I hate Alexa ranking so much because it ruins my business. :(

Comment: I understand. However, it is your job to ascribe the value of your company. Businesses that rely on Alexa rankings are foolish and very behind the times. You must be able to ascribe your companies value and how that is *not* reflected in foolish metrics such as Alexa.

Comment: The best way to effect a useful Alexa rank is to drive more traffic to your site. The ranks you offered are low. One reality is that perhaps the people who visit your site are not the type of people who would use the Alexa toolbar. You can encourage your users to install the Alexa toolbar. Better yet, make your site attractive the more people thus driving traffic. This is the best solution. Enough traffic, then Alexa will have enough sample data to rank your site better.

Comment: Just now my website got updated again on Alexa and it went back to 4 million. Maybe it was a glitch in the system or something? It just jumped back from 18 million to 4 million.

Comment: Again. It is bad statistical analysis based upon a flawed premise that effective analysis can be had on a selective sample. That is impossible. Day 1 in any SA 101 class. You have to understand that there is a lot of garbage data surrounding website performance found all over the web. Just Google your domain name without the TLD or www and see how many sites try and get into the game. Almost all of them are junk. Alexa knows very little about most sites and cannot properly tell you the performance of your site as well as you can. Simply put. They haven't a clue. Forget about them.

Comment: Performing statistical analysis against a selective group is biased. For example. It I were to study automobiles, and only collect statistics for Asian cars, then whatever analysis I perform cannot be extrapolated to reflect what is true about American cars or European cars. The same is true for the self-selected Alexa users. It can only tell you what is true for these uses and cannot be extrapolated to reflect the reality of the Internet as a whole. Alexa, SA speaking, is a biased example set and therefore invalid.

Comment: I understand your concern however. Any business person who is requiring Alexa rank is foolish. I have been an IT and Business consultant all of my adult life with Venture Capitol experience. Businesses that base investments upon a metric that can easily be manipulated and is not a reflective of actual performance are conducting bad business. You have to find a way around this. Fortunately, this trend of requiring Alexa rank is ending.

Comment: Thanks for dedicating your time to reply back to me. :D You say that the trend of requiring Alexa rank is ending but it's the complete opposite for me. I keep seeing it everywhere with companies that I try to do business with. The first thing they ask me is, "What's your Alexa ranking" and my response is "somewhere in the 5 million range" then they don't take me seriously. Anyways, I will keep working to improve my Alexa rank because it's vital for my business.

Comment: I understand. The trend away from Alexa is a new one. Too many companies have made bets based upon this metric and they are beginning to realize the error of their ways. As with any trend, it takes a while to gain critical mass. It may take years.

Comment: Thats now 100% true ... The Alexa toolbar is not the only metric that they have ... you can register to Alexa and they provide a tracker script, this way you can signal Alexa about your visits.

Comment: @BrunoSacco There are only 2 ways that Alexa collects data by their own admission; the toolbar and their JS bug. As well, Alexa's toolbar is only compatible with 2/3rds of the current browsers- mobile primarily not being covered. You cannot normalize for bias against a population that you do not know. Alexa's claim is that they represent the entire Internet and that they normalize for bias is absolutely impossible- no question. Alexa is junk, has been junk, and will always be junk. Do not buy their Bull.

Comment: And the top reason for not trusting Alexa, the interested audience is only web site operators who think that Alexa has value. They're the most likely to have it installed as Cargo Cult SEO tells them it's important and that they need to install the toolbar to get ranking. Don't drink the Koolaide, don't eat the Applesauce... There's no UFO waiting behind the moon to take your soul when you transcend. If it's vital for your business, you are in the wrong business.