# Alexa ranking and the pageview measure

Tags: alexa

How can pageviews differ very much for 2 sites that have nearly the same global ranking in Alexa?

I have nearly the same global ranking but my pageviews are 1/50th of my comparison.

What is it in the measure that accounts for the unexpected proximity in global ranking when pageviews differ by factor 50?

The data is:

Site 1: My site. Global ranking 105 000. Local ranking 10 000 in India. My google analytics reports that I have abt 100 daily visitors and abt 800 daily pageviews.

Site 2, the comparison, has global ranking 98 000 in Alexa but with 7000 daily visitors and 50 000 daily pageviews. Local ranking 51 in Tanzania.

How can the global rank not differ that much when pageviews and visitors differ that much?

Comment: Why care? Alexa is useless and inaccurate.

Comment: @JohnConde  Now I care because you say it's inaccurate. Alexa is still my best way to verify some claim that a site has x number of users / pageviews and I find that it is not a linear relation when it should look like a linear relation between pageviews and global rank. Maybe I missed something or it's just inaccurate because that can't measure very well.

Comment: It is not the best way to verify traffic because their data *is very inaccurate*. You have no way to verify a user's claim about traffic and pageviews without seeing their analytics data. Anything else is a wild guess at best.

Comment: I can second that! Alexa is pure junk!! It is impossible for Alexa to know your sites performance externally. It is a scam really. Here is an answer on that: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58602/what-is-wrong-with-alexa-ranking/58606#58606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexa rank is measuring the rank, according to the number of people visited your website and who have the Alexa toolbar (or any other SEO toolbar with Alexa rank tracker) installed. And who has such toolbars nowadays? mainly SEOs and webmasters. If your targeted audience isn't one of them, then your Alexa rank will be low, but visits high

Comment: It is statistically impossible for Alexa to measure anything. 1/3rd of web users are not possible for Alexa to track, and of the remaining 2/3rds, 1/3rd Alexa elects not to track. You cannot extrapolate metrics for a population you do not know. It is Statistics Analysis 101 day one stuff. Alexa is pure junk! Plain and simple. Just thought you should know. Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I recognize the problem with self-selection in statistics. My business partner also said that Alexa is inaccurate because of the distribution of their toolbar is not representative.