# Is alexa give more importance to that website which purchase its pro plan?

Tags: seo, pagerank, ranking, alexa

I want to decrease ,y website's alexa rank. So which steps are required to decrease alexa rank and is it true that alexa give more importance that website which purchase its pro plan?

What will happen if we purchase pro plan of alexa?

Comment: What will happen is you will make Alexa a richer company and yourself poorer. Nothing else.

Comment: This answer will help you to know that alexa means absolutely nothing(!): http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58602/why-do-alexa-rankings-for-a-site-fluctuate-by-millions-day-to-day/58606#58606 Do not waste your time paying attention to alexa. Seriously. Just move on. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

There are few options for doing this. But first of all, I want to tell you that Alexa is not important for anything. But, if you like to be in circle of unimportance and circle around irrelevant stuff, here's what you can do to decrease your alexa rank:

**Claim your site** - Claiming you site in Alexa tool is an effective approach to decrease alexa traffic rank fast.

Also, use Alexa Toolbar and Alexa Widgets it's going to be instant decresal. There are more options, but this is enough to do what you want.

> What will happen if we purchase pro plan of alexa?

Don't do this because it's a waste of money.