# My Big Rock webserver analytics does not matches with Alexa and Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, webserver, alexa

I am managing a website with WordPress.

As per Alexa (Amazon Product), 90% of my visitors are from India and 5% from US. As per Webserver (Big Rock), 75% from India, 9% from Canada, 5% from US. However as per google Analytics, 60% from UK, 30% from US and 10% from Iran.

It is a huge discrepancy. All the above companies are reputed.

I would really appreciate if any one can address my queries

Comment: And 90% of visitors to your site don't have the required Alexa toolbar installed to make Alexa relevant (which it never is).

Comment: Alexa is pure junk and here is why: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58602/why-do-alexa-rankings-for-a-site-fluctuate-by-millions-day-to-day/58606#58606

Answer (score 1):

Here are few steps to make your life more easier:

1. Remove Alexa from your calculations.
2. Use Google Analytics.
3. Live happy.

Comment: Okay. I am slow. I just read this. You crack me up! Dead on answer. Cheers!!