# Why don't Google page speed and Alexa site speed data match?

Tags: page-speed

Google PageSpeed Insights says my blog fitlogy.com is 88 / 100.

However Alexa says it is very slow:

[image]

Which data should I pay attention to?

Comment: That is because Alexa is JUNK! Stop looking at it.

Comment: I am not trying to be cruel. This answer sums it up perfectly. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99318/my-big-rock-webserver-analytics-does-not-matches-with-alexa-and-google-analytics/99322#99322

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to testing server's location. Some servers, like the one your current website is hosted on, respond quicker to specific locations compared with others.

For example, if your server is in Germany, testing its speed or response time from China and America gives contradicting results.
You should see what locations Google and Alexa use to test your websites speed.