# Is AdWords worth using for forums?

Tags: google-adsense, traffic, forum

I have a free £75 coupon for Google AdWords but it says they require me to pay £25 to use the coupon so i am questioning if i should run a campaign or not since i run a forum earning with Adsense rather than a shop or business.

If i set the daily budget to £5 for my keywords they say i get around:

```
197+ Daily clicks
11K+ Daily impressions
```

Now if i calculate:

My payment £25 would give me 5 days worth of ads then:

```
985+ Daily clicks
55K+ Daily impressions
```

Then the £75 would give me 15 days worth of ads then:

```
2,955+ Clicks
165K+ Impressions
```

The totals would be:

```
3,940+ Clicks
220K+ Impressions
```

My forum is very new, Adsense has been on there for a week and earnings are:

```
721 Page Views
1.4K Impressions
Page RPM: £0.18
Last 7 Days: £0.13
```

So it seems they estimate i would earn £0.18 Per 1000 Page Views which would give me these earnings:

```
3,940+ Total Clicks = £7.092 Earnings (£17.908 Loss)
```

Considering this is suppose to be £100 advert campaign which looks like it would give me a loss of £17.908 that doesn't seem too great.

Would there be any benefit or reason i should run this advert campaign?

For example might it rise my page ranks in google after the ads finish, get me new users and backlinks etc and possibly lead to me generating more Adsense earnings in the future? This seems possible but a bit of a gamble for £17.908 right now.

Are my calculations correct and does anyone have any advice regarding this?

Comment: One thing. Through out Alexa as having any value whatsoever. Alexa is pure junk. Really. We hate the word around here. Here is why. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58602/why-do-alexa-rankings-for-a-site-fluctuate-by-millions-day-to-day/58606#58606 As for your question, I like the detail. It may be soliciting an opinion more than a factual answer. Adwords does not help with rank in Google. It does give you traffic however. The question is, can you have a campaign that returns enough users to justify the cost? That is your question in a nutshell.

Comment: Thanks, I know Alexa rank doesn't really mean much but i have always found it useful for discovering high traffic sites. I just removed it from my question. Were my calculations accurate though? I have never used Adwords before but have always considered it if i ran a online shop but i found the £75 voucher and thought it would probably help me get a load of views and possibly profit but it doesn't look too great. I imagine lots of new website owners just pour cash into Adwords with not much returns or pure loss after doing the maths.

Comment: I have no idea. I never used Adwords. For my sites, it was not something I chose to do. I simply had too much to do. Most are shutdown (I am retired and have a farm, antiques business, rentals, etc.) with new smaller niche sites on the way. As for a forum, I used to create forums in the early days and I focused on user activity more than new users. Activity will get you new users even if you need to get your friends involved. Bribes work. ;-) I will date your annoying sister if... well... maybe not! I do like your question. I am sure a lot of people have wondered the same thing. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

For the forums, you need to play a long game and make the forum as an asset. As of now, you planning to send the traffic to the forum and make money right? It may or may not work, It depends on a lot of factors.

What if you try this way,

use the traffic to increase the forum registrations and more interactions. By doing this your forum will have more content, community and a brand. Long term game.

You can enable demographic profile in the google analytics of the forum property. You can get a clear demographics data of your forum.

It's a cycle, the more you get users, the more content you can generate, the more page views, the revenue you can get in the long run.

Think of it.

Good Luck.