# Determine Google search term for page hits

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, google-search, alexa

I am a Web developer but my knowledge of SEO tools and techniques is scant. An SEO professional told me that Alexa SEO tool has the ability to determine the Google search terms leading to page hits. However, I did not think it was possible for anybody except Google to know the search terms leading to page hits. Unless, of course, Google has allowed them to access analytics information.

So, is there any technique that can be used to determine the Google search terms directly (without subscribing to Google Analytics)? Also, is it true that Alexa SEO knows those search terms?

Comment: Alexa is absolute trash. And you are right, no one except Google can tell you about performance in Google. Same with Bing. Do not listen to any SEO who utters the word Alexa unless he is referring to a girl. Here is why: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58602/why-do-alexa-rankings-for-a-site-fluctuate-by-millions-day-to-day/58606#58606

Comment: Google Analytics doesn't tell you anything special either.   Only Google Search Console has "search analytics" with search terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexa SEO (like other similar tools) is going to give you information about the traffic they'd expect to come to your site based on estimations they make about the volume of traffic. I can't confirm Alexa's sources but many of these tools use [AdWords's traffic estimator service](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201705/TrafficEstimatorService). This is estimated traffic and doesn't represent traffic specific to your site.

For organic search terms, Google doesn't pass keyword information to other tools. The only source where you can get some of this information is the Search Analytics report in Google Search Console. Keep in mind this information shared in Search Analytics has some potential issues as well. [Here](https://moz.com/blog/google-search-console-webmaster-tools-reliability) is a good review of the reliability of that data.