# Is site speed connected with Alexa Traffic rank?

Tags: seo, google-search, google-ranking, alexa

Alexa ranking really a big controversial topic. It's really critical to determine how it ranks sites. You know that if you are working in SEO field that your performance is measured by Alexa Rank for your site.

I observe that if the site speed very good, then it gets more traffic and a better Alexa Rank.  If the speed slows down, it gets worse. So is it interconnected?

Exactly how much visitor or organic search does a website need to get a better Alexa rank?

Comment: As somebody that has been doing SEO for nearly 20 years, I have never used Alexa rank as any sort of success metric.   I don't know anybody in the field that does.   Alexa rank can give you a quick indication about which large sites are more popular but it has many problems.   It doesn't do a good job with small sites for which it gets very little data.  It is skewed by non-page views (Doubleclick which serves ads had a very good rank for many years.)   It relies on people who install their toolbar for data and those people don't represent internet users as a whole.

Comment: Yes..i also agree with you. But the thing is if one of your delivered duty is to keep the rank low in Alexa also Dealing with the high amount of Organic Search..then what can anyone do...

Comment: Alexa doesn't have anything to do with organic search though.  It measures any traffic that has the toolbar installed, regardless of traffic source.   That traffic can be bought.   It is a horrible metric for SEO.

Comment: Really Horrible..and Confusing. Thank you. But the problem is, the person who only judge a site by it's Alexa Rank..Then What can be the answer. It's Difficult to understand them

Comment: You need to educate your customer. It is that simple. This answer should give you a good start. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58602/why-do-alexa-rankings-for-a-site-fluctuate-by-millions-day-to-day/58606#58606 Alexa is such a POS that it should be embarrassing to AOL.

Answer (score 1):

Is traffic to the site the most important metric?  You should consider engagement (time on page, pages per visit, etc.) and what visitors do when they visit the site (submit a form, download a white paper, sign up for a webinar).  What people do on the site may be more important than how many visitors, since it's easy to drive traffic, but harder to drive qualified visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Alexa's rank is based solely on their panel(the users downloaded their toolbar and therefore share their surfing with alexa). They all about the numbers of users and not the time it takes them to load the pages. of course you can assume that if the load time is drastically higher less users will load the pages which in the long term will affect alexa rank. but in the big picture, there is no connection between the two.